# Azure Function App results not always showing up in Monitor

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

Results from an invocation of an Azure function do not always appear in the **Monitor** section in the Azure portal.

[image]

I trigger the Azure function from a DevOps pipeline, from the **Test** tab in the function in Azure portal, and from a web browser. The results usually show up in Monitor when triggered from the **Test** tab, sometimes when triggered from a web browser, and usually not when triggered from the DevOps pipeline.

I can see that the function has been successfully invoked by inspecting the target of the script, which configures another system.

Is there a more reliable way to view the results of a function app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options

1. enable application insights
2. you can enable OMS to subscribe to all events from your function app and then query OMS for the data that you need
3. create an output binding to table storage, writing out exactly the data that you wish to track and then you will be able to query that storage table for what you need to see

Comment: which option did you go with and do you need any assistance